# Is it possible to use `content-for` to include stuff in page structure on Ember CLI?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Currently Ember CLI generates an index page with some obscure helpers: `content-for` head, head-footer, body and body-footer.

Is it possible for the app developers to leverage those helpers to include additional code to, say, the page `<head>`? The [doc](http://www.ember-cli.com/#appindexhtml) is tiny and focused only on "addons can use this".

I have a page with a very specific CSS and would be better if it was loaded through a separate `<style>`, but I wanted to include it in the page `head` tag...

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this Ember CLI Inline Content add-on that leverages `content-for` in your `index.html` - https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-cli-inline-content . I've used it myself last week, it works great!

Comment: that seems good but it's still not what I'm looking for. It would be cumbersome to include CSS styles in a JS code through strings...

Comment: You could just put the styling inside the head, like any other stylesheet. However, you would not have any benefit from the asset compilation/minimisation.

Comment: @bouke I'm not interested in asset compilation. I just wanted to add some bits of specific CSS to the head tag. They're just for that page, it's pointless on having them mixed in with the other project-wide styles.

Answer (score 0):

[This issue on GitHub](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/2407) says

> > I've also just ended up here after looking for some documentation on how to conditionally customise index.html [...] Am I correct in my parsing of this discussion that the only way to do this at present is to create an in-repo-addon?
>
> Yes, that is the easiest/best way to do this right now.

This answer is from 2016 though.

Additional information on addons for Ember CLI can be found [here](https://cli.emberjs.com/release/writing-addons/). Specifically for dynamic header tags there already exists [this addon](https://github.com/ronco/ember-cli-meta-tags).